# Gradle equals assign operator vs space

Tags: gradle, groovy

You can assign value to a property of a `Gradle` API class in two ways thanks to `Groovy` syntax.
I see `Gradle` uses equals assign operator consistently through the examples (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html).

For example:

```
compileJava {
  sourceCompatibility = '15' // Gradle userguide convention 
  targetCompatibility '15'   // Also valid syntax 
}
```

What is the difference, and why should I use one over the other?

So far I understand that `sourceCompatibility = '15'` is syntactic sugar for invocation of property setter from here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/55ebbdcbff8a379f2afe0394e8d68583a0c471e3/subprojects/language-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/compile/AbstractCompile.java#L172.

Does it mean that `targetCompatibility '15'` is also syntactic sugar to invoke same setter method, as there is no `targetCompatibility()` method defined in `AbstractCompile` class?

Comment: I have deleted my answer based on your response, but it is indeed the case that `targetCompatibility '15'` is method invocation and that `sourceCompatibility = '15'` is assigning a value to a property.  I can appreciate that they may not look that way, but I do believe that is what those are.  I am sorry that caused confusion, but I do believe that is the case.  Best of luck!

Comment: You should leave your answer I might approve it! Thanks for help! I see that second syntax is really method invocation, while I still don't get it. Can be that groovy magic adds this "method", or one can invoke setter, without set prefix, this is my only conclusion. In documentation targetCompatibility is property. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile:targetCompatibility.

Comment: "You should leave your answer I might approve it!" - I am not happy with it.  It was a confusion causing answer.

Comment: It may very well be some sort of mixin or module that Gradle adds to take advantage of Groovy's [metaprogramming](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html). Example: [DependencyAdderExtensionModule](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/dsl/dependencies/DependencyAdderExtensionModule.java)

Comment: "Does it mean that targetCompatibility '15' is also syntactic sugar to invoke same setter method" - No.  That is a request to Groovy's dispatch mechanism to invoke a method named `targetCompatibility` and pass `'15'` as a parameter.  Depending on the context where that happens, different routes may be taken, but none of them involve Groovy invoking same setter method.  Setter methods could be involved in something like `sourceCompatibility = '15'` though.

Comment: I thought the question was about the syntax differences between something like `sourceCompatibility = '15'` and `targetCompatibility '15'`.  If the question is about how Gradle implements this, putting breakpoints in methods like https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/646d38370272a33f53cb6993c216ad97fe61c17d/subprojects/language-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/compile/AbstractCompile.java#L172-L174 may shed some light.

Comment: Yes question was about the syntax difference. It didn't make sense for me that second one is plain function invocation as there was no function defined in Gradle `AbstractCompile` class with that name.
So thanks to comments/answers from you guys, with debugging it I see that behind the scenes Gradle makes Decorator of `JavaCompile` Task class at runtime. For every setter method it creates a standard method without a set prefix, that is something new for me. Jeff you were on point since the beginning, thanks!

Comment: "Jeff you were on point since the beginning, thanks! " - I am glad you got it worked out.  All the best.